# On which context inventory gets changed in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I have created a custom checkbox and I have to mark it to true whenever any thing is changed on the record. My problem is I do not have to use lastmodified date because lastmodified is not working as all the items are coming in search. Whenever an item is shipped, it's inventory is changed but i would like to know on which context it changes. It is possible to do with workflow. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inventory change is via different record types in NetSuite, and will not be via item.

I think you will need to write User Event Script or workflow on following record types to detect all Inventory changes:

```
1) Item Fulfillment
2) Item Receipt
3) Item Transfer
4) Inventory Adjustment
```

Apart from these there are other mechanism to make an impact on inventory, I am not sure if NetSuite allows user event script or workflows on these:

```
1) Inventory worksheet
2) Physical Count
```

For the case of Item being shipped from a Sales Order an Item Fulfillment is created, so, you can deploye your workdlow or user event on Item Fulfillment in that case.

**Edit**: Transfer Order isn't applicable as @bknights suggested. Inventory alterations would be actually made by Item Fulfillment/Receipt records in case of Transfer Orders.

Comment: Thanks Prasun. Do I need to create user event script for each record e.g item fulfillment to check inventory changes on items and check the box of respective items?

Comment: I would suggest create a single user event and deploy it for all applicable record types. Considering your case you may want to start with Item Fulfillment first.

Comment: FWIW transfer orders only commit inventory (like the default action of approving a Sales Order) so on hand inventory changes are only affected by 1,2,4,5. 

Inventory worksheets don't have a user event so if you are updating an external system you'll probably want to have a periodic full update. This is pretty straightforward with a saved search. 

Generally a physical count is reported to Netsuite via an Inventory worksheet.